# Apache Airflow: Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued

Tags: airflow, executor

Our airflow installation is using CeleryExecutor.
The concurrency configs were

```
# The amount of parallelism as a setting to the executor. This defines
# the max number of task instances that should run simultaneously
# on this airflow installation
parallelism = 16

# The number of task instances allowed to run concurrently by the scheduler
dag_concurrency = 16

# Are DAGs paused by default at creation
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True

# When not using pools, tasks are run in the "default pool",
# whose size is guided by this config element
non_pooled_task_slot_count = 64

# The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
[celery]
# This section only applies if you are using the CeleryExecutor in
# [core] section above

# The app name that will be used by celery
celery_app_name = airflow.executors.celery_executor

# The concurrency that will be used when starting workers with the
# "airflow worker" command. This defines the number of task instances that
# a worker will take, so size up your workers based on the resources on
# your worker box and the nature of your tasks
celeryd_concurrency = 16
```

We have a dag that executes daily. It has around some tasks in parallel following a pattern that senses whether the data exists in hdfs then sleep 10 mins, and finally upload to s3.

Some of the tasks has been encountering the following error:

```
2019-05-12 00:00:46,212 ERROR - Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance: example_dag.task1 2019-05-11 04:00:00+00:00 [queued]> finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?
2019-05-12 00:00:46,558 INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY
2019-05-12 00:00:46,561 WARNING - section/key [smtp/smtp_user] not found in config
```

This kind of error occurs randomly in those tasks. When this error happens, the state of task instance is immediately set to up_for_retry, and no logs in the worker nodes. After some retries, they execute and finished eventually.

This problem sometimes gives us large ETL delay. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: I have this same problem too. This was a simple DAG. How did you fix it?

Comment: @alltej I provided my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We fixed this already. Let me answer myself question:

We have 5 airflow worker nodes. After installing flower to monitor the tasks distributed to these nodes. We found out that the failed task was always sent to a specific node. We tried to use airflow test command to run the task in other nodes and they worked. Eventually, the reason was a wrong python package in that specific node.

Comment: I'm facing similar problems . Could you point out which package coused it ?

Comment: @JiafanZhang I forget which package. actually it depends on your code. If your code is using a class but its related package is not 'pip install' in one of workers. The exception will happen.

Comment: I had the same problem and above solution solved it.
In my case, task(let's call task1) used to fail in one of the worker nodes (lets call worker1). task1 logs were available in all the worker nodes except worker1.
This shows that, something is wrong with worker1.
I reverified it by running `airflow test dag_id task_id execution_date` and it threw the error message.

Comment: one of my workers was out of HDD. Airflow was working, tasks were running in other workers, but those tasks that were assigned to the problematic node were failing with the above error. Resolve any issues with workers and this should stop occurring.

Answer (score 8):

We were facing similar problems , which was resolved by

`"-x, --donot_pickle"`  option.

For more information :- https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#backfill

Comment: We are not using the backfill command. The problem is in our airflow ETL

Comment: Why do you think this solved the issue? I'm trying to understand the issue better, we're experiencing it as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing very similar symptoms in my DagRuns. I thought it was due to the ExternalTaskSensor and concurrency issues given the queuing and killed task language that looked like this: `Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance: dag1.data_table_temp_redshift_load 2019-05-20 08:00:00+00:00 [queued]> finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?` But when I looked at the worker logs, I saw there was an error caused by setting a variable with `Variable.set` in my DAG. The issue is described here [duplicate key value violates unique constraint when adding path variable in airflow dag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581440/duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-when-adding-path-variable-in-airf?rq=1) where the scheduler polls the dagbag at regular intervals to refresh any changes dynamically. The error with every heartbeat was causing significant ETL delays.

Are you performing any logic in your wh_hdfs_to_s3 DAG (or others) that might be causing errors or delays / these symptoms?

Comment: i am having this problem too. what is the fix? i tried to create DAG with different dag_id and task_id hoping it it got stuck by some dag_id or task_id but I still see the problem with the different dag_id or task_id.

Comment: Checking the worker logs was the key to the solution, even when the task was being reported in success I found there that there was an error: `{taskinstance.py:845} INFO - Dependencies not met for ... dependency 'Execution Date' FAILED: Execution date 2021-06-16T23:29:31.114396+00:00 is in the future (the current date is 2021-06-16T23:27:06.958673+00:00)`

Answer (score 1):

In MWAA (AWS hosted Airflow), we solved this issue by adding an Airflow configuration option in the MWAA environment where the configuration option of "celery.worker_autoscale" was set to "5,5" (note we have a mw1.medium that had a max concurrent tasks of 10, our airflow version is 2.2.2, and we have about 20+ "jobs" that run in parallel with 6 tasks for each job). We found how to solve this buried in [this git issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/10790#issuecomment-690223705)

The config "celery.worker_autoscale" is the maximum and minimum concurrency that will be used when starting workers. Essentially what I believe is happening is that Celery was running up the max number of processes (sensors, tasks, etc.) on one worker while the other worker was running 0, at which point it would send the error "Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued." I think this better distributes the processes that celery has to run on its workers which helps with logging each state of a process. This logging is used within Airflow to identify state transitions between tasks.

For more info on Airflow and MWAA configs, [see this medium post](https://medium.com/@sukul.teradata/understanding-open-source-airflow-and-mwaa-concurrency-e5f5e5fef675)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and was able to resolve it by using the `{ "donot_pickle": "True" }` JSON key-value pair in the Configuration JSON (Optional) section.

[image]