# Airflow - Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?

Tags: airflow

I cannot start my DAG because of this Error. I thought it was because of sensor, but as I edited my Dag couple of times it is still showing this problem so it is not connected to the code of my DAG.

Error message - "Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued. Was the task killed externally?"

Comment: Helpful links [link1](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html#zombies-undeads), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56119107/3679900), [link3](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-dev/201808.mbox/%3CCAJujfrDDV5i7W74w0Z3vLj+ONyNBc1MfT9-AKMtpnfXF6SzFLg@mail.gmail.com%3E)