# Airflow - Executor reports task instance finished (failed) although the task says its queued

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

I recently upgraded my MWAA env from 2.4 to 2.6 (latest). I notice there was a [breaking change](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/changelog.html#:%7E:text=Removed%20deprecated%20RedshiftSQLOperator%20in%20favor%20of%20the%20generic%20SQLExecuteQueryOperator.%20The%20parameter%20that%20was%20passed%20as%20redshift_conn_id%20needs%20to%20be%20changed%20to%20conn_id%2C%20and%20the%20behavior%20should%20stay%20the%20same) in between the versions which I have updated. Otherwise, nothing has changed in my DAGs.

However, almost all DAGs are working fine except for one DAG. I keep getting '***

> Executor reports task instance <TaskInstance:
> dag_name.task1
> manual__2023-09-12T09:11:57+00:00 [queued]> finished (failed) although
> the task says its queued. (Info: None) Was the task killed externally?

***'. It's not limited to the same task everytime. However, it's mostly the same DAG. Nothing has changed in my code except for the operator but I am struggling to find the root cause.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56119107/apache-airflow-executor-reports-task-instance-finished-failed-although-the-ta) but even that is not helping.

Here are my DAG settings:

```
default_args = {'start_date': datetime(2023, 3, 2),
                'retries': 1,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=20),
                'email_on_failure': False}


with DAG(
    dag_id="lazy_load_dag", 
    start_date=datetime(2023, 3, 2), 
    schedule_interval="30 22 * * *", 
    tags=['lazy_load'],
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup = False,
    description='Some description',
    default_view='graph', #grid, graph, duration, gantt, landing_times
    on_failure_callback=None,
    on_success_callback=None,
    # max_active_runs = 1,
    # concurrency=10,
    # on_failure_callback=send_email
    ) as dag:
```

I have also attached my configuration options[image]

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Updating my ***celery.worker_autoscale*** from 5,5 to 6,6 seems to solve the problem